# Implementing SoundCloud API in iOS app - getting error

Tags: objective-c, ios, soundcloud

I have followed the instructions to include the sound cloud api into my app at the following link exactly:

https://github.com/soundcloud/CocoaSoundCloudAPI

But when I get to the part where I need to - #import "SCUI.h"

I get an error SCUI.h file not found.

I have tried everything I can think of to fix the issue.

I am using Xcode 4.3.3 with iOS SDK 5.1

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Have you add the CocoaSoundCloudUI submodule to your project?

Comment: Check your header search paths.

Comment: I have added the submodule. The problem was that I hadn't got the correct header search paths. But now when I run my app I get +[SCSoundCloud shared]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x196200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering the question you posed in your comment. I haven't used this particular library, but it seems from looking at the source that you're trying to use a function that the library's author marked as private. If you *really* need your code to be able to use `[SCSoundCloud shared]`, you could include the header `SCSoundCloud+Private.h`, and that should fix your problem... but you should be able to access all the functionality you need by calling `[SCRequest perform...withAccount:[SCSoundCloud account]...]`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$PROJECT_DIR` with recursive to the `Header Search Path` for your target.